# "Talk / Say" functionality in a game

Tags: c#

So I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to implement a "talk" function in my game. I'm new to C# programming but I've been doing as much reading and experimenting as I can with the language.

This is what I have so far:

```
Comm comm = new Comm();
string message = null;
if (InputBox.Text == "say " + message)
            {
                OutputBox.AppendText(comm.do_say(message));
            }

class Comm
{
    public string do_say(string message)
    {
        return "You say: " + message + "\n";
    }
}
```

Now, this doesn't work. I think I know why, but I can't seem to figure out just how to redo it so it does work... I've tried to replace:

```
(InputBox.Text == "say " + message)
```

with

```
(InputBox.Text == "say {0}", message)
```

and it doesn't work either. So, now I'm out of ideas on how to make this work. I tried searching stackoverflow and google for answers but came up with nothing.

Any help or hints on how to fix it would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't know what the `message` is in advance, right? You need to search for the "Say ", and take the rest of the string as input.

```
if(InputBox.Text.StartsWith("Say ")) 
    OutputBox.Text += InputBox.Text.SubString(4);
```

`SubString(4)` will return whatever's after the first 4 characters in the string, everything after the `"Say "`

Comment: Thanks! This worked beautifully. So simple and exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) here, but C# doesn't support pattern matching.  In other words, simply writing

```
if (InputBox.Text == "say " + message)
```

does not automatically assign "foo" to message whenever the user types "say foo".

Instead, you should probably use regular expressions, which are implemented in C# with the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class.  Try something like

```
Match m = Regex.Match(InputBox.Text, @"^say\s+(.*)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
{
    OutputBox.AppendText(Comm.GetScreenoutput(m.Groups[1].Value));
}
```

You don't need to make `do_say` an instance method, so in the code above I have assumed that `Comm` is transformed to

```
static class Comm
{
    public static string GetScreenOutput(string message)
    {
        return "You say: " + message + "\n";
    }
}
```

This code follows the naming conventions for C# code, using [Pascal case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_case) for method names.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (InputBox.Text.ToUpper().StartsWith("SAY "))
{
    OutputBox.AppendText(comm.do_say(message));
}
```

This will check if the user used the word say, regardless of the case used.

Comment: In addition to the marked answer I used this too. Thanks for the help.